# Class 'Sentinel' not found (Laravel 4)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I'm using Laravel 4 and rydurham/Sentinel (https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel). I'm able to log in users, register users and display the Sentinel views I've customized perfectly fine. The config changes I've made register fine. However, when I include:

```
{{ Sentinel::check() }}
```

or

```
{{ Sentinel::guest() }}
```

I get the error `Class 'Sentinel' not found`. I notice there is no Sentinel Facade in `$aliases`, and running `composer dump-autoload` does not fix this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you importing the Sentinel class? use Sentinel;

Comment: Doesn't change anything. I think this is because `rydurham/Sentinel` and `cartalyst/Sentinel` are not the same thing, even though they're both named Sentinel. One is some guy's project on GitHub and the other is some paid junk through Packalyst. I can do `Sentry::check()` just fine though.

Comment: Here's the "Sentinel" I was using: https://github.com/rydurham/Sentinel

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I'm using `rydurham/Sentinel` and not Cartalyst's `Sentinel` package. They are two different things. `rydurham/Sentinel` includes the facades for `Sentry` though, so you can use:

```
{{ Sentry::check() }}
{{ Sentry::guest() }}
```